# Using fitted vs. lm method in quadratic regression

Tags: r

this is my first post on stackoverflow, which will probably be obvious soon because this is a pretty basic question. I'm preparing to do a quadratic regression in R and noticed there seem to be 2 ways to do it: with lm() or fitted(). The lm() examples I've found are generally:

```
 quadraticModel <- lm(y ~ x + x^2)
```

However, other examples that use the fitted() method include a term I within the lm() statement:

```
 fitted(lm(data~factor+I(factor^2)))
```

That brings up 2 questions for me: under what circumstances would I want to use fitted() instead of just lm(), and what does the "I" mean in the fitted() method?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Directly from the `?fitted` help page:

> fitted is a generic function which extracts fitted values from objects returned by modeling functions.

Try reading the help pages first for questions like this. `lm()` does the modeling, `fitted()` just extracts the fitted values from the model. They are two very different operations.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding `I`. As you can read in the man page:

> In function ‘formula’.  There it is used to inhibit the
>             interpretation of operators

If it is not clear just see what is going on if you use `I`:

```
> lm(mpg ~ I(wt ^ 2) + wt, data=mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ I(wt^2) + wt, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      I(wt^2)           wt  
     49.931        1.171      -13.380
```

and if you don't

```
> lm(mpg ~ wt ^ 2 + wt, data=mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt^2 + wt, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt  
     37.285       -5.344
```

Comment: hello, I looked at the R documentation and found an explanation of the I term... but I still have a question. I can see in the illustration you provided that wt^2 is being considered as a separate term from wt in the first example, but if they are being added together in the second model, why does I(wt^2) + wt (1.171+-13.38) not equal the wt term (i.e. -12.209 instead of -5.344) in the 2nd model? shouldn't x^2 and x be consistent values, respectively, regardless of whether they are considered separately or not? thanks again.

Comment: It is a quite broad question and far out of scope for SO. Long story short there is nothing strange here. You can go through all the math with pen and paper. If you choose algebraic approach you'll see that both models leads to completely different design matrices. If you prefer more statistical point point then you'll see that you get different number of DF for residuals, different p-values and so on.

Comment: I did try going through the math and still don't get where the difference lies.

Comment: If you're still not sure what is going comparing model matrices should help: `with(mtcars, model.matrix( ~ wt^2 + wt))` vs `with(mtcars, model.matrix( ~ I(wt^2) + wt))`